# Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Record<Key, Value>'

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
const foo = <Key extends keyof any, Value>() {
  type Rec = Record<Key, Value>
  const a: Rec = {}
}
```

On the 3rd line typescript given an error that `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Record<Key, Value>`. Why is that happening?

Comment: Because `{}` isn't a `Record<Key,Value>`.

Comment: Because, it is assigning empty object although you defined `Record` type with attributes.
If you want to assign, you should edit `Record` type by making all the attributes as optional(?)

Comment: This is the documentation for the Record type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype It suggests that a Record is somehow a Map type. Therefore an empty map should be acceptable. This is either a documentation problem or some wiered misconception. Therefore: A good question.

Comment: this could be as simple as `type Rec = Partial<Record<Key, Value>>`

Answer (score 8):

In my case generic parameter was `string` and it's okay to assign empty object to `Record<string, unknown>`.
Reason why it is not accepting `{}` is that `Key` parameter could be concrete string union type like `'prop1' | 'prop2'`. In this case user is forced to add these properties to the object