# Generic type for key of Record

Tags: typescript

I would like to make a class which stores some stuffs inside an object

```js
class BusServiceFactory<T extends string = string> {
  private readonly store: Record<T, Map<string, (val?: string) => unknown>> = {};

  subscribe(uid: string, eventName: T, callback: (val?: string) => unknown): void {
    this.store[eventName] ??= new Map();
    this.store[eventName].set(uid, callback);
  }

  unsubscribe(uid: string): void {
    Object.values(this.store).forEach((handler) => handler.delete(uid));
  }
...
}

enum CustomEvent {
  EventA = 'evtA',
  EventB = 'evtB',
  EventC = 'evtC',
}

export const CustomBus = new BusServiceFactory<CustomEvent>();
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

The main idea is to use a generic type for the key of `store` so that I can pass an enum when I want to be exhaustive on the possible keys.

With that code, I got `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Record<T, Map<string, (val?: string | undefined) => unknown>>'` on the line where I assign `store`.

I get also `'handler' is of type 'unknown'` in the `unsubscribe` method and I don't really understand why

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Record<Key, Value>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64526194/type-is-not-assignable-to-type-recordkey-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by saying `store` is a `Record<T, Map</*...*/>>`, you're requiring that it have properties for each possible value of `T`, but `{}` doesn't have any properties. You could work around that using `Partial`, but I think for your use case, a `Map` is a better fit (and it also solves the "`handler` is of type `unknown`" problem), see comments:

```
class BusServiceFactory<T extends string = string> {
    // Changed this to a `Map`
    private readonly store: Map<T, Map<string, (val?: string) => unknown>> = new Map();

    subscribe(uid: string, eventName: T, callback: (val?: string) => unknown): void {
        // Updated this because `this.store` is now a map
        let entry = this.store.get(eventName);
        if (!entry) {
            entry = new Map();
            this.store.set(eventName, entry);
        }
        entry.set(uid, callback);
    }

    unsubscribe(uid: string): void {
        // And this
        for (const entry of this.store.values()) {
            entry.delete(uid);
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCCuEDKBTATgNwJbBQMTGABcB7NATwB4AVaFADyJQDsATGCItLZgc2gC80Ttz4A+aAG8AUNDnQA9AugBhABZg+KVtCJqsMUtDDQABgFkwAB1Oz5V7hjBNoaFGFYlmIcsNJuALmhLKxoAGmDrShEeXgiACicQAH4gmL4ASkEJeGYAa2YSAHdmMQkhZhQiyKt4jIBuaTs5CHgAIwhgbjaUePgsVjSuWIiUDBYiADkwAFsUIOoI4DAQEDbCPKDEldS-UV4sgRz8wpKMoIwSAalm+TklaABVK1ZnbV19GB7lxBQzPQMADpOGQUKZoAZoKdjNAZtZbncQCgiHRmFxfEIARBgf4UIDeMj4mMJtM5g0EfIsAAzaDxACEEwoWRkd1Z8kZGKhVRqdUabLZWJxoOBhOJaNJKFGaKZfP5AF8KXIOSKiH0BksVmsNuS7grbrlWh0ulgemrBntYudoJdriz+Q8AIJsD4GRXQKlkWnALycVHo6AkGmCkFuQFJeAoCB1Zluu7K1goJFMM06+W3BV3B6A7PSPUseAzVSIUgzACi4zRNzu5YmDsE0AARGMiA6G2FbjW0bB602MERYG2OxWiCoe82VIO8-QrGQUd7mL6VMWSDMEDAKty16hMDh8IR-FQlyCy8OxLygA)

Answer (score -1):

export type ValidatorSchema = Record<T, { validations: string[] }>;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).